# __gt__ vs > and so on

Tags: python, operators

some python classes have some operators such `__gt__` or `__lt__`, They have been named from fortran language.

What's difference between above operators and `<` or `>` ?
Is't better to use `__operators__` than `<`  or `>` ?

Comment: see https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html

Comment: `2 > 2.5` is not the same as `(2).__gt__(2.5)`

Answer (score 9):

The `__gt__` method **is** the implementation of `>`, likewise the other comparison operators have similar methods:

> `object.__lt__(self, other)`
>
> `object.__le__(self, other)`
>
> `object.__eq__(self, other)`
>
> `object.__ne__(self, other)`
>
> `object.__gt__(self, other)`
>
> `object.__ge__(self, other)`
>
> These are the so-called “rich comparison” methods. The correspondence between operator symbols and method names is as follows: `x<y` calls `x.__lt__(y)`, `x<=y` calls `x.__le__(y)`, `x==y` calls `x.__eq__(y)`, `x!=y` calls `x.__ne__(y)`, `x>y` calls `x.__gt__(y)`, and `x>=y` calls `x.__ge__(y)`.

[Source](https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__)

Generally one uses the operators `>`, etc. in code. But you need to use `__gt__` and similar for implementing the functionality on own classes.

You should (almost always) not use the `__gt__` methods directly in your code, because the data model also defines some special cases that are handled outside of these methods.

For example if one operand doesn't implement the comparison then it tries the reverse comparsion with the operators swapped:

```
>>> (1).__gt__(2.5)
NotImplemented

>>> (2.5).__lt__(1)
False

>>> 1 > 2.5
False
```

If you ever need to "functional comparison" you should use the `operator` module:

```
>>> from operator import gt
>>> gt(1, 2.5)
False
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference between them.

**When you should use `>`**

When doing stuff regularly, e.g.

```
>>> 80 > 70
True
>>>
```

**When you should use `gt`**

When `map`ping, or `sort`ing or something, to not have `lambda`:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3]
>>> list(map((2).__gt__, l))
[True, False, False]
>>>
```

So don't need:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3]
>>> list(map(lambda x: x < 2, l))
[True, False, False]
>>>
```

Comment: What if `l` contains `1.5`?

Comment: Really not a good example to use `list(map((2).__gt__, l))`. If you have a homogeneous list then it might work, but if you have a heterogeneous list then there's a chance you'll end up with `NotImplemented`s in the result.